# Add two arrays of integers into an array of arrays so it creates coordinates pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, one with x coordinates and one with y coordinates. I need to create a new array of arrays that group the coordinates.

```
yCord = [30, 29, 31, 32];
xCord = [0, 1, 2 ,3];
```

Here is what I had.

```
var cordPairs = {};
xCord.forEach((key, i) => cordPairs[key] = yCord[i]);
```

But that pairs the values in an object, I need an array now.

```
{0: 30, 1: 29, 2: 31, 3: 32}
```

Desired result:

```
cordPairs = [[0, 30], [1, 29], [2, 31], [3, 32]]
```

Comment: if the desired result is `cordPairs = [...]` why do you create `graphData = {}` ?

Comment: `cordPairs = xCord.map((x, i) => [x, yCord[i]])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the data in `array` format so this should work:

```js
const yCord = [30, 29, 31, 32];
const xCord = [0, 1, 2 ,3];
const coords = xCord.map((el, index)=> [el, yCord[index]]);
console.log(coords);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the x and y values in an array and transpose this array.

```js
const
    transpose = (r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]),
    yCord = [30, 29, 31, 32],
    xCord = [0, 1, 2 ,3],
    result = [xCord, yCord].reduce(transpose, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Very cool approach. I stumbled a bit over the name `transpose`, as such method usually flips the matrix. But "transpose" also has a second meaning of "change the context", which is applicable here.

Comment: @AlexPakka, do you have a better name for it?

Comment: @NinaSholz too late, now it is stuck in my head. It is precise and it works, I would keep it. The whole folding/reduction is definitely a `zip()` - well known FP and reactive concept. But the reducer... ok, it transposes elements from one array to another, no big deal. You have some cool answers, btw. I learned something new today, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### The other answers are great - but...

This may actually be a situation where, instead of creating a method that can perform the process, you would actually want to create a new Constructor function that will return an object with the innate ability to iterate how you want.

```
function CoordinateArray(x, y) {
  if (y.length != x.length) return Error("CoordinateArray: Incorrect Array Bounds");
  let i = 0;
  return {
    y,
    x,
    [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
      while (i < this.y.length) {
        yield [this.x[i], this.y[i]];
        i++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A functioning code example:

```js
let yCord = [30, 29, 31, 32],
  xCord = [0, 1, 2, 3];

function CoordinateArray(x, y) {
  if (y.length != x.length) return Error("CoordinateArray: Incorrect Array Bounds");
  let i = 0;
  return {
    x,
    y,
    length: x.length,  
    [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
      while (i < y.length) {
        yield [this.x[i], this.y[i]];
        i++;
      }
    }
  };
}

let coords = new CoordinateArray(xCord, yCord);

console.log([...coords]);
```

### Why would you do it this way?

When utilizing something in a coordinate system it's likely that the functionality of looping over coordinates is a commonality within your code. A.e. It happens more than once, and if it needs to be extended, the functionality may be needed again.

Creating a Constructor for this purpose allows you to create code that lends itself to higher `clarity` and `concision`.

It also allows for greater innate control over how you code.

---

### What do I mean by that?

Creating a method/function that simply iterates over the two Arrays once and returns a bundled coordinate Array is well and good - but let's say that somewhere down the line you simply need to adjust all the `x` values. With a normal function you would either need to write conditions, or perform the function and, afterwards, perform additional work to get the results you want. A.e.:

```
getCoordinateArray(xCord, yCord) //perform a lot of work
  .map(([x,y]) => [x*2,y]);      //perform more work
```

Whereas if you provide yourself with a Constructor with innate iteration mechanics, you could save yourself the hassle while providing more iteration options:

```
let coords = CoordinateArray(xCord, yCord); //initial work
coords.x = coords.x.map(i=>i*2); //minimal work
```

It may not be plain to see, but by doing it the Constructor way, you're adjusting the Object as minimally as possible while still maintaining a functional paradigm. You don't worry about the total results, you only adjust what you need to and the outcome will be as expected. Furthermore, it's crystal clear what you're adjusting in the second example `coords.x`, whereas in the first it's more of a jumble.

To extend on this as well, you can also abstract away simple mechanics as the above to make your intentions even more clear. Simply add on a method to your Constructor:

```
 function CoordinateArray(x, y) {
  return {
  ...
   //new method
    move: function(s, c = s.split("")[0]) { this[c] = this[c].map(new Function(c,"return" + s)) },
   ...
  }
}
```

And the above will become this instead:

```
let coords = new CoordinateArray(xCord, yCord); // initial work
coords.move("x*2"); // minimal, clear, work.
```

```js
let yCord = [30, 29, 31, 32],
  xCord = [0, 1, 2, 3];

function CoordinateArray(x, y) {
  if (y.length != x.length) return Error("CoordinateArray: Incorrect Array Bounds");
  let i = 0;
  return {
    x,
    y,
    move: function(s, [c,] = s.split("")) { this[c] = this[c].map(new Function(c,`return ${s};`)) },
    length: x.length,  
    [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
      while (i < y.length) {
        yield [this.x[i], this.y[i]];
        i++;
      }
    }
  };
}

let coords = new CoordinateArray(xCord, yCord);
coords.move("x*2");
console.log([...coords]);
```

Which, I think anyone will say, is much easier to read - but more importantly with that readability it isn't **costing** you anything. Even though there is no assignment to `coords.x`, it isn't mutating your data. Normally with operations you'll see things like `x = x.map();` at each step, which does showcase immutability, but it's redundant and obfuscatory when it needn't be.

---

Yes, a simple function as provided by the other answers may be all you need - but if you are performing coordinate manipulation often in your code, I would urge you to consider alternative routes other than stacking multiple functions. A Constructor would allow you to keep what you need with the benefit of extreme clarity and flexibility with your data and methods, and minimal impact on Scope.

All this being said...

**Your use case will decide the best option!**

Again, the other answers are perfectly valid ( in fact, a few of the other people who answered I purposely follow because they are very knowledgeable and inspiring)  - I only offer this answer to provide more insight into operating with things like coordinate systems. I've written many apps, components, etc, that have utilized them and I've put a lot of time into the process of making them clear and effective for myself as well as others!

Hope this helped! Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, love this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the index of the two arrays, Package the pairs in a javascript array and pus to make an structure of them:

```
yCord = [30, 29, 31, 32];
xCord = [0, 1, 2 ,3];
var cordPairs = [];

for(var i = 0; i < xCord.length; i++)
{
  cordPairs.push([xCord[i], yCord[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Long story short, you want to zip those arrays. With libraries like lodash, it's as simple as

```
cordPairs = _.zip(xCord, yCord);
```